# Lombok does not create getter and setter methods after using @Data

Tags: java, lombok

I have gradle spring boot project and I added Lambok dependency in build.gradle.
I created one model class and want to use lombok. I have added @Data annotation but still setter and getter methods are  not generated.
Sample code :

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class TestLambok {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String summary;

}
```

Comment: Did you install lombok or lambok? Anyways, you should install it in your IDE and restart it.

Comment: The methods are only generated in bytecode not sourcecode. You need a plugin for your IDE to see them there.

Comment: some IDE's also require the installation of a lombok plugin, did you install that?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat  I have install lambok in my IDE and restart it but still I am not able to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use Lombok Plugin, you need the following steps (at least on IntelliJ):

- Install Lombok Plugin
- Enabling Annotation Processing
- Restart IDE

For more information you can read this post: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Answer (score 0):

Install the Lombok plugin first then you can use the @Data annotation. Please note that you won't physically see the getters, setters and toString() appear in your class aktjouy Lombok will create it

Answer (score 0):

Im using visual studio code. There is an extension called "Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code".

Installing this allowed the auto generated methods to show when querying the properties of the object