# why I am not able to access the get and set method using @Getter and @Setter Annotation in Spring Boot Application? || Lombok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, lombok

why I am not able to access the get and set method using @Getter and @Setter Annotation in Spring Boot Application?

```
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;

public class Card {
    
    @Getter//(lazy = true) 
    @Setter
    private int id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String cardvalue;

}
```

In my Controller class it says both methods are undefined.
Note: In pom.xml added Lombok dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and verified as well whether file downloaded successfully in Maven Dependencies or not.

Is there any configuration to do in order use that methods using annotation?
please help!

Comment: which ide you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue, Maybe you need to add one Lombok plugin, that will fix the issue at least for me or others

Could you please refer the below pages? And follow the steps to add the Lombok plugin

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018276/how-to-access-getter-and-setter-methods-using-lombok)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea#:%7E:text=I%20had%20to%20install%20Lombok%20plugin%20too%20to%20make%20it%20work.&text=make%20it%20work-,But%20if%20you%20are%20on%20a%20Mac%2C%20make%20sure%20you,in%20the%20following%20two%20places%3A&text=File%20%2D%3E%20Other%20Settings%20%2D%3E%20Default%20Settings%20%2D%3E%20Build,of%20%22Enable%20annotation%20processing%22.)

[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236104/gradle-build-fails-on-lombok-annotated-classes)

Please refer  [IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596222/lombok-does-not-create-getter-and-setter-methods-after-using-data)

Please refer  [Eclipse/STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803948/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on IntelliJ you need to download the Lombok plugin. You can download it from `Preferences -> Plugins -> Lombok`
[image]